# Actionscript 3 Export to text file

Tags: actionscript-3, text, air, export

Just playing around with Actionscript 3/AIR and could not find a decent tutorial on allowing an export to a simple txt file in the same folder. I've kind of fudged together this code and was hoping someone could take a look and offer a pointer on where I am going wrong.

Currently getting the error message 
`5006:An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition:file`, doSave

```
package  {

    import flash.events.Event;


    public var file:FileReference = new FileReference();


    public function doSave( event:Event ):void
    {
       var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
       data.writeMultiByte ( txtField.text, "test" );
       file.save( data, "MyTextFile.txt" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out my first example on my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842214/run-an-as3-function-only-once/26849578#26849578

Comment: Well not much code to it, that is the entire .as file. :/

Comment: Sorry, little late. But yeah managed to get it working in the end!

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors, consider posting your solution.  Either as an answer, or an edit to an existing answer if related.

Answer (score 0):

Your error actually has nothing to do with saving a file.  It is because you lack a class defintion in your package (all code, vars need to be encased in a class).  Try this: (where MyFile is the placeholder for the name of .as file)

```
package  {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class MyFile {
        public var file:FileReference;

        public function doSave(text:String):void
        {
            file = new FileReference();
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSaveComplete, false, 0, true);

            var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            data.writeMultiByte(text, "utf-8" ); //use a proper charset for it to work right
            file.save( data, "MyTextFile.txt" );
        }

        private function onSaveComplete(e:Event):void {
            file = null; //free up the file reference to be garbage collected now that the save is complete
        }
    }
}
```

---

Then, your other code should look something like this:

```
saveButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,saveButtonClick,false,0,true);

function saveButtonClick(e:Event):void {
    var save:MyFile = new MyFile();  
    save.doSave(txtField.text); 
}
```

---

If you wanted to forgo the save as box that lets the user pick where to put it, and just save the file somewhere directly without user interaction, this would be a way to do that:

```
var file:File = new File("app:/MyTextFile.txt"); //the application directory, which may or may not be allowed write access
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("MyTextFile.txt"); //use this alternatively which is default profile save location for your application

var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeMultiByte(data);
fileStream.close();
```

Comment: Ok making some progress now, no longer getting the 5006. However showing a 1046 on FileReference. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because you're not importing the FileReference class. I'll update the answer

Comment: Whoops, ok thanks! Looks like I will need a import flash.utils.ByteArray as well. Last error I've noticed is a 1067: Implicit coercion of a value type flash.display:DisplayObject. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the full error?  and what line does it point to?  Not likely related to any of the code posted, though your textField var is not defined or set anywhere so it may have to do with that.

Comment: Line 1 1067:Implicit coercion of a value of type export to an unrelated type flash.display:displauObject. For some reason it repeats it 3 times. Same thing to line 1.

Comment: Well, type export sounds like something you've made?   This isn't related to the class file posted.  Can you edit your question to include your other code (especially line 1 of whatever class or timeline is throwing the error)

Comment: Only using the .as with the code provided above. It links to export, which is just a usual AIR file with a simple text box in it. I would update the original question but there is nothing really to update it with.

Comment: Nothing more can be done with what's posted (it's not the cause of your error), show whatever class or block of code makes a call to the `doSave` function.  Show the code for your export file and whatever the main document class is that links everything together.